# Updating TextView and running Animation on rows in RecyclerView is causing memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

In our application, we have recyclerviews with many rows in them. Each one has a TextView whos text is a timestamp representing how long the row has been there, as well as an ImageView that may or may not need to be animated based on the item the row corresponds to.

The complication is this: The TextView needs to be updated every second, and the ImageView may need to be animated every few seconds to shake. While watching the Memory Monitor in Android Studio, the memory climbs and then seems to garbage collect, but does so in a loop for the entirety of the time I remain on this page of the app. When I leave the page with the ListView on it, memory drops down and seems to hold steady.

[image: Memory Monitor]

Here's the current way i'm updating the rows:

```
listRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                ArrayList<SystemEventsAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> holders = mAdapter.getCurrentActiveViews();
                for (SystemEventsAdapter.SimpleViewHolder holder : holders) {
                    holder.alarmDuration.setText(holder.systemEvent.getAge());

                    if (!holder.systemEvent.IsSilenced && holder.systemEvent.isSquawking && !holder.imageAnimator.isRunning()) {
                        holder.imageAnimator.start();
                    }
                }
                listHandler.removeCallbacks(listRunnable);
                listHandler.postDelayed(listRunnable, 1000);
            }
    };
    listHandler.post(listRunnable);
```

the getAge() method just turns the milliseconds the event has been open into the HH:mm:ss format using String.format().

Here's the relevant code from inside the adapter:

```
public ArrayList<SimpleViewHolder> getCurrentActiveViews() {
    synchronized (activeHolders) {
        return activeHolders;
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(final SimpleViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    activeHolders.add(holder);
}

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(SimpleViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);

    holder.imageAnimator.cancel();
    activeHolders.remove(holder);
}
```

Here is the SimpleViewHolder class:

```
public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView alarmType, origin;
    public TextView alarmDuration;
    CircularImageView userImg;
    RelativeLayout alarmFieldHolder;
    View colorBand;
    public SystemEvent systemEvent;
    public ObjectAnimator imageAnimator;

    public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //Items for individual event
        userImg = (CircularImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_image);
        alarmType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_type);
        alarmDuration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_duration);
        alarmFieldHolder = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_field_container);
        colorBand = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.color_band);
        origin = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_origin);

        imageAnimator = new ObjectAnimator();
        imageAnimator.setPropertyName("rotation");
        imageAnimator.setFloatValues(0,-15,15,0);
        imageAnimator.setDuration(600);
        imageAnimator.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
        imageAnimator.setTarget(userImg);
    }
}
```

Previously, i've tried putting a Runnable on each individual row so that it would update itself, which still seemed to be leaking memory. I also tried using using Animator instead of ObjectAnimator, which didn't seem to help either.

The result is that the app performs fine at first, but after about 8 hours of these events getting updated, the whole app has slowed to a crawl.

**Update:**
Here is the code for the entire adapter

```
public class SystemEventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SystemEventsAdapter.SimpleViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<SystemEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<SimpleViewHolder> activeHolders = new ArrayList<>();
private Activity activity;
private int selectedAlarm;

public SystemEventsAdapter(final Activity activity, ArrayList<SystemEvent> alarms) {
    this.events = alarms;
    sortAlarms();
    this.activity = activity;
}

public int getCount() {
    return events.size();
}

public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView alarmType, origin;
    public TextView alarmDuration;
    CircularImageView userImg;
    RelativeLayout alarmFieldHolder;
    View colorBand;
    public SystemEvent systemEvent;
    public ObjectAnimator imageAnimator;

    public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //Items for individual event
        userImg = (CircularImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_image);
        alarmType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_type);
        alarmDuration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_duration);
        alarmFieldHolder = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_field_container);
        colorBand = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.color_band);
        origin = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_origin);

        imageAnimator = new ObjectAnimator();
        imageAnimator.setPropertyName("rotation");
        imageAnimator.setFloatValues(0,-15,15,0);
        imageAnimator.setDuration(600);
        imageAnimator.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
        imageAnimator.setTarget(userImg);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return events.size();
}

public ArrayList<SimpleViewHolder> getCurrentActiveViews() {
    synchronized (activeHolders) {
        return activeHolders;
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(final SimpleViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    activeHolders.add(holder);
}

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(SimpleViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);

    holder.imageAnimator.cancel();
    activeHolders.remove(holder);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final SystemEvent event =events.get(position);
    if(event.Image == null || event.Image == "") {
        Picasso.with(activity).load(R.drawable.system_events_with_border).fit().into(holder.userImg);
    } else {
        Picasso.with(activity).load(event.Image).fit().into(holder.userImg);
    }

    holder.alarmType.setText(event.getEvent());


    if(event.Origin == null || event.Origin.equals("")) {
        holder.origin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.origin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.origin.setText(event.Origin);
    }

    holder.alarmDuration.setText(event.getAge());

    holder.alarmFieldHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkExpandedAlarm(event.ID)) {
                    selectedAlarm = event.ID;
                    FragmentTransaction fragTrans = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    System_Event_Expanded_Fragment frag = new System_Event_Expanded_Fragment();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("alarmID", event.ID);
                    b.putString("mode", "normal");
                    frag.setArguments(b);
                    fragTrans.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_out_bottom, R.animator.slide_in_bottom, R.animator.slide_out_bottom, R.animator.slide_in_bottom);
                    fragTrans.replace(R.id.right__frag_container, frag).addToBackStack(null);
                    fragTrans.commit();

                }
            }
        });
    holder.systemEvent = event;
}


@Override
public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate( R.layout.system_event_field, parent, false);
    return new SimpleViewHolder(v);
}


public boolean checkExpandedAlarm(int AlarmID) {
    if (selectedAlarm != 0 && AlarmID != selectedAlarm)
        activity.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    return AlarmID != selectedAlarm;
}

public void updateAlarms() {
    events = AtmosDesk.getAlarmManager().getSystemEvents();
    sortAlarms();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void sortAlarms() {
    Collections.sort(events, new eventComparator());
}

private class eventComparator implements Comparator<AtmosEvent> {
    @Override
    public int compare(AtmosEvent o1, AtmosEvent o2) {
        return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding `android:largeHeap="true"` in your manifest?

Comment: Why should this help? I think it will just delay his problem

Comment: @JGagnon Are there any orientation changes which triggers the memory leak?

Comment: The app is locked to landscape orientation, so it doesn't rotate.

Comment: Could you post the whole code of your adapter?

Comment: @beeb I've updated the post with the full adapter code

Comment: Mhh. I can't see a problem with this code... Such problems are really annoying because you said your app works fine at the beginning. I think you should use a memory leak tool.

Comment: Are there any specific tools you'd suggest?